# Window Scroll Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was making a blog, and tried to use `$(window).scroll(function()`, but something prevents it from working.

I try to add class named `scrolled` to body when user scrolls down. Any idea which would prevent it working properly? Console doesn't give any error regarding to this.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 100) {
            $("body").addClass("scrolled");
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("scrolled");
        }
    });
});
```

LIVE PREVIEW

http://personaii-demo.tumblr.com/

Comment: Remove `$` from function. If you want to protect function then write `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: @mdesdev Thanks, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Remove overflow:auto property added to the container. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes a `$` argument, but you're not passing anything in so it gets overwritten, you should do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 100) {
            $("body").addClass("scrolled");
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("scrolled");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I use wrapper called #sb-site, might that be the problem? I tried .scroll and it worked, but I don't need behaviour like that.

Answer (score 0):

Better JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {  
        $('body').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() >= 100);
    });
});
```

On your website, I see no css associated with `.scrolled` anywhere even if I apply it via the console.

Comment: It's so short I like it :)

Comment: Hey, why did you close document ready with empty brackets `})();` ?

Comment: @AlienWebguy Doesn't seem to work with me though it looks pretty working. I put  $(function() {
     $(window).on('scroll', function() {  
         $('#sb-site').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() >= 100);
     });
 })(); on my JS, but still no working. That #sb-site is wrapper that handles background color.

Comment: @mdesdev typo, my bad. Aleksi, try now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working shorthand solution, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/jJkj2/)

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) ? $("body").addClass("scrolled") : $("body").removeClass("scrolled");
  });
});
```

Also if you're using jQueryUI then you can add a little animation to class changing process with `switchClass()` e.g.

```
var scroll = ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) ? $("body").switchClass("default","scrolled", 1000) : $("body").switchClass("scrolled","default", 1000);
```

***Note:** Also don't forget to include jQuery/jQueryUI libraries in your document.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I use wrapper called #sb-site, might that be the problem? I tried .scroll and it worked, but I don't need behaviour like that.